# In Cognos Report Studio how to display chart values vertically outside bar chart

Tags: report, cognos-10

In Cognos Report Studio how to display chart values vertically outside bar chart[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, at least with the standard chart library of Cognos 10. Anyway I'm not 100% sure but I think I had the same request some time ago and found no solution.

Comment: Thanks Tripanosomagambiense. Even I tried to figure out but I was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a visualization using JSON

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/c_cr_rptstd_charts_11_1.html